# How to Remote Debug WorkFlow Events Sites 9.1

Tags: event-system, workflow, sites-9.1

**Trying to remote debug sites 9.1 workflow events.**

After finally getting visual studio 2013 remote debugging connection to the Dev CMS Server from Amazon Workspace,
I attached to the TcmWorkflowAgent.exe to debug my Workflow ActivityInstance Events.
(As indicated in
**Debugging Content Manager
https://docs.rws.com/783502/502913/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/debugging-content-manager/procedure**)

I have added the file path to the .pdb
Debug | Options| Debugging | Symbols | Symbol file(.pdb) location

Adding a breakpoint we see a problem
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Has anyone encountered this issue before or know how to resolve it?

I have googled for related articles but these relate to much older versions of Tridion.

**SDL Tridion Event System Newbie Perspective by Alvin Reyes**
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-tridion-event-system-newbie-perspective

**Debugging a Tridion 2011 Event System**

https://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/debugging-tridion-2011-event-system.html

**Remote Debugging in Visual Studio Made Easy(ish)**

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-made-easyish

**Getting Started with Tridion Event System !!**

https://tridionwithanupam.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/get-started-with-tridion-event-system/

Answer (score 2):

When Debugging, Attach to multiple processes.
Although I want to catch the Workflow events (TcmWorkflowAgent process), you must also attach to IIS (w3wp process) for the breakpoint symbols to load.

Comment: Good background, Chris. I've heard someone mention "attach to all of them" before (perhaps from @MihaiC) but I didn't realize why. :-)